# Javascript calling eval on an object literal (with functions)

Tags: javascript, import, eval, google-apps-script

Disclaimer: I fully understand the risks/downsides of using eval but this is one niche case where I couldn't find any other way.

In Google Apps Scripting, there still is no built-in capability to import a script as a library so many sheets can use the same code; but, there **is** a facility built-in where I can import text from a plaintext file.

Here's the eval-ing code:

```
var id = [The-docID-goes-here];
var code = DocsList.getFileById(id).getContentAsString();
var lib = eval(code);
Logger.log(lib.fetchDate());
```

Here's some example code I'm using in the external file:

```
{
  fetchDate: function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dateString = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    return dateString;
  }
}
```

What I'm aiming for is to drop a big object literal (containing all the library code) onto a local variable so I can reference it's properties/functions like they're contained in their own namespace.

Comment: @AbePetrillo Can an object literal be read in and eval'd directly. If so, how? The answer is yes; by wrapping the object in parentheses it can be evaluated as an anonymous function that returns the object literal in a manner that can be assigned to a variable. It's kind of a hackish workaround but I was trying to find a way to import in a Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace `var lib = eval(code);` with:

```
var lib = eval('(' + code + ')');
```

When the parens are omitted, the curly braces are being interpreted as markers of a block of code. As a result, the return value of `eval` is the `fetchData` function, instead of a object containing the function.

When the function name is missing, the code inside the block is read as a labelled anonymous function *statement*, which is not valid.

After adding the parens, the curly braces are used as object literals (as intended), and the return value of `eval` is an object, with the `fetchData` method. Then, your code will work.

Comment: Actually without parens the value of eval is an error because `fetchData: value` is interpreted as a label and an anonymous function expression isn't a valid value for a label.

Comment: No, this works flawlessly. I should have figured that somebody on Stack Overflow would know the nitty gritty details of eval. I was wondering why the hell toString was returning a [function] from the eval. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot evaluate

```
{
  fetchDate: function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dateString = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    return dateString;
  }
}
```

Because it is not a valid expression (Object literals on their own are interpreted as blocks. fetch: function () { } is not a valid expression).

Try

```
var myLibName = {
  fetchDate: function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dateString = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    return dateString;
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 Your your solution worked perfectly but I'm trying to make it so the namespace is configurable where eval is being called. Thanks anyway, maybe this will help somebody else.