# How to add Google Analytics event label to Angulartics2?

Tags: google-analytics, angular, angulartics

In [Angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2), how do you pass the event label to Google Analytics?

Currently I have this code:

```
<a type="button" [routerLink]="['SecondPage']" angulartics2On="click" angularticsCategory="Click" angularticsEvent="Homepage">Click me</a>
```

When using the Analytics debugger for Chrome, it shows an event being fired which passes category and action. Looking at the code in GitHub makes it look like it is possible to supply a label, but I'm not clear what attribute needs adding to the anchor tag? angularticsLabel doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer provides the correct method, but it is also [necessary to wrap the Object literal in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949274/javascript-calling-eval-on-an-object-literal-with-functions) due to an [`eval` in the code](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/master/src/core/angulartics2On.ts#L49):

```
angularticsProperties="({label: 'some label'})"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the angularticsProperties parameter

```
angularticsProperties="{label: 'some label'}"
```

cf. https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/issues/22

Comment: Based on the code this looks correct, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: Are you checking in Real-Time reports, or in GA Debugger to see if the event shows up correctly?

Comment: Google Analytics debugger. It shows: 
Running command: ga("send", "event", {eventCategory: "Click", eventAction: "Homepage", eventLabel: undefined, eventValue: undefined, nonInteraction: undefined, page: "/", userId: null})

Answer (score 0):

The new version now (1.1.9) is:

```
[angularticsProperties]="{label: 'YourLabel'}"
```

I just udpated README file by a PR [here](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/commit/80c67ffdbd21f2e106eab2e1c84b3c76bb2fc2f2).