# Converting a string to an *almost* JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, parsing

So I have a string that looks like this:

```
'{utopia:1,word:2,sentence:3,tourism:4,home:5}'
```

I'd like to convert it to an object that looks like:

```
{utopia:1,word:2,sentence:3,tourism:4,home:5}
```

I tried using JSON.parse() on the original string but got 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1'. I think this is because the keys of the object don't have quotations around them (in a classic JSON object, it would be like "utopia":1,...)

Not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Are "values" of that always numbers? What's the source of this string?

Comment: Worth pointing out that *with* `eval` (and all the **danger** that goes with it) it can be done by enclosing in parentheses like: `eval('(' + str + ')')`  As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949323/1563833)

Comment: I think you mean **from** an almost-JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first replace { and } in string with empty strin then yourstring.split(',')
After that [items].reduce((a, v) => ({ ...a, [v]: v}), {}) to build your object